# Identical UI on two windows but different functionality per window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**WPF Application**:

I will have the `identical` **UI** in two windows.

Let's say we have following **win** with **identical** fields: `name,address,dob,phoneNo etc.` for adding

1. customer details
2. staff details

> > So is there a way so i can built `single UI` and use it on two different windows and write the `logic per window`.

I am kind of new to **WPF** and I have searched about it n find out **Page**   used for `navigation` on same window and **UserControl** for custom control as calendar etc. And i think this is not what i am looking for..

Trust me, there are lot of `identical UI` in my application so i need to work around it..

> So is it possible or is there another great way for this??
>
> Or not possible and i have to copy and paste the xaml :( ??

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MVVM design pattern.  If you have two separate class object say Customer and Staff, but same name field/properties in object, you can use control's Binding Property to populate the fields and Windows's DataContext property to set the object as data source.  There is one advantage also here that you don't need to write set/get values from controls.  As binding property works both way, if object value changes, it will update on UI and if value manually modify by USer on UI, it will reflect in class object immediately.

Comment: I am very new to MVVM. I am just learning about it. So, it will take time for me to grasp your idea. Anyway thanks for reply.

Comment: Window.DataContext = objCustomer; and then in your XMAL for each control you can bind control like <textbox Text={Binding Path=Address1 Mode=twoway} />.

Comment: I agree with this answer. If you can use the same base model for customer and staff, this would even be easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share UI code between different pages or windows of your application, you need to create a `UserControl` that contains the XAML and exposes configurable settings as `DependancyProperty`'s and actions as `Event`'s or `Command`'s.

Re. "I am kind of new to WPF": It's the same process as if you'd be doing this in WinForms, create a custom control that does what you want it to do and re-use it in multiple places.

Comment: ThankYou for reply. I will have few textboxes, comboBox etc. in `UserControl`. But how to get the values from those controls in `Win` because actually they are in _UserControl_. I am naive on these.


And I am quite sure that you are saying to overcome these with `exposing configurable settings as DependancyProperty and actions as Events or Command`. But i don't have idea about it :(. Though I am searching info. about it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a - hopefully - simple example of what you want, I think. I'm going to assume that while your UI is the same they are bound to different Models or ViewModels. I'll create my `UserControl` first:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControlDemo.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserControlDemo"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Text="{Binding Path=objName}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

It just contains a `TextBlock` with a `Binding` to something called `objName` and notice that I'm using the `Loaded` event.

The code-behind:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{



    public string customObject
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(customObjectProperty); }
        set { SetValue(customObjectProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty customObjectProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("customObject", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl), null);


    public string objName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(objNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(objNameProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty objNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("objName", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl), null);


    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var obj = CustomObjectFactory.GetCustomObject(customObject);
        objName = obj.GetTypeName();
        DataContext = this;
    }
```

OK, let's see what we got here.I have two dependency properties,`customObject` and `objName`. The fact that they are dependecy properties provide functionality to bind them to controls in the UI. We bound objName to the `Text` property of the `TextBlock` in the UserControl above.

In the `Loaded` event, I'm using a factory method to return the correct object type. See below.

The `customObject` property, however, is set during the initialization of the control but to see that we have to go to out MainWindow.xaml (or the window where your UserControl will be used):

```
<Window x:Class="UserControlDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserControlDemo"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Tab 1">
                <local:MyUserControl customObject="Object 1"/>

            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Tab 2">
                <local:MyUserControl customObject="Object 2"/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As you can see, the MainWindow.xaml doesn't hold very much "own" code just a `Grid`, a `TabControl` and two `TabItem`s. In each of the TabItems there's a reference to the UserControl but notice that because we have a dependency property called `customObject` in `MyUserControl` I can pass a value to MyUserControl.

That value is then used together with a `Factory` method and an `Interface` to load two different types depending on which TabItem I'm in.

Below, I have created two classes; `Object1` and `Object2` which implements the `ICustomObject` interface.

```
public class Object1 : ICustomObject
{
    public string GetTypeName()
    {
        return this.GetType().ToString();
    }
}

public class Object2 : ICustomObject
{
    public string GetTypeName()
    {
        return this.GetType().ToString();
    }
}
```

As you can see, these classes has one method which only returns the class name in a string.

To be able to dynamically return the correct object type depending on which window you're currently in we have to use a `Factory method`.

```
public static class CustomObjectFactory
{

    public static ICustomObject GetCustomObject(string ObjectName)
    {

        switch (ObjectName)
        {
            case "Object 1":
                return new Object1();


            case "Object 2":
                return new Object2();

        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

The result is that when I open Tab 1, I can see a TextBlock with the text "UserControlDemo.Object1" in it while in Tab 2 I see "UserControlDemo.Object2"

This means that I can add another TabItem and quite easily add another type to displa in my UI without altering my code very much.

I hope this was some help for you.